# Correct way to use domain layer in ddd architecture golang

Tags: go, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I am creating a microservice that is based on clean architecture. The code is provided below for reference. I am bit convoluted on whether having central domain struct definition for bootstrapping the services(redis in the following example code), is appropriate or acceptable in place of having struct definition local to each layer and then using them in adapter layer

```golang
//domain/redis.go
package domain
type Database struct {
    Client *redis.Client
}


//domain/policy.go
package domain
type Policy struct {
    Name            string    `json:"name" binding:"required"`
        Data            string    `json:"data"`
}
type PolicyRepo interface {
    SavePolicy(policy *Policy) error
    GetPolicy(name string) (*Policy, error)
    GetField(name string, fields ...string) ([]interface{}, error)
    UpdatePolicy(name string, fields ...string) error
}

//repository/policy.go
package repository
type policyRepo struct {
    db *domain.Database
}
func NewPolicyRepo(db *domain.Database) domain.PolicyRepo {
    return &policyRepo{
        db: db,
    }
}
func (repo *policyRepo) SavePolicy(policy *domain.Policy) error {
    if err := repo.db.Client.HSet(context.Background(), "domain:"+policy.Name, map[string]interface{}{
        "name":          dom.Name,
        "data":            dom.Data,
    }).Err(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
// other interface func definiton

//.../redis.go
package rdb
func NewRedisDB(host string, port string) (*domain.Database, error) {
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", host, port),
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    })
        
       //Error handling
    return &domain.Database{
        Client: client,
    }, nil
}

//.../adapter.go
func Init(redisDB *domain.Database) {
    //Initialise repositories..
    policyRepo := repository.NewPolicyRepo(rdb)
    ...

    //Dependency injecting this in usecases
}

func main() {

   rdb, err := rdb.NewRedisDB(conf.REDISHOST, conf.REDISPORT)
   if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error booting up the redis server")
   }
   adapter.Init(rdb)
}
```

I find the above implementation to be more decoupled and more aligned with domain layer of clean arch. But I haven't found a single open source project that implement the clean architecture in the way mentioned above.

They follow the usual conventional way of using the local struct definition in each layer and reusing it in adapter function make it more coupled which goes against principle of domain layer in clean architecture. If anyone has anything to correct and comment over this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT:** I understand that above question doesn't come out clearly. I will try to explain the usual convention that i was talking about with previous example. If one has to define a service say redis, we usually define entities local to that layer like below and then reusing across different layer by importing that specific module

```golang
//services/redis/redis.go
type Database struct {
    Client *redis.Client
}

func NewRedisDB(host string, port string) (*domain.Database, error) {
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", host, port),
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    })

    //Error handling
    return &Database{
        Client: client,
    }, nil
}

//repository/policy.go
package repository
type policyRepo struct {
    db *rdb.Database
}
func NewPolicyRepo(db *rdb.Database) domain.PolicyRepo {
    return &policyRepo{
        db: db,
    }
}

//.../adapter.go

func Init(redisDB *rdb.Database) {
    //Initialise repositories..
    policyRepo := repository.NewPolicyRepo(redisDB)
    ...

    //Dependency injecting this in usecases
}
```

As a result entities defined in infrastructure layer will then need to be accessed by usecases and repositories which violates dependency rule of clean architecture.

Comment: The open source Go community tends to optimize for the simplest, easiest to follow approach. There's not an emphasis on design-driven architecture — honestly there's a bit of counter-culture to avoid it unless absolutely necessary from experiences in other languages. But what your describing seems reasonable, and many companies do similar things. I would just advise caution: don't create solutions before you really need them. Questions about DDD and "Clean Architecture" are opinion-based so not sure what answers will fit here.

Comment: Your last paragraph is confusing to me: first you say that each layer gets its own local struct to implement something, but then you say that "it" is re-used in an adapter. Those two contradict eachother, can you update your question to explain what you mean?

Comment: @JoryGeerts I have updated the question as asked. Please do let me know if any further clarification is needed. And sorry for the late reply, was busy with work.